# PHP unlink(); No such file or directory

Tags: php

I searched everywhere for this problem and can't find the solution. I have this:

```
<?php
  $file_name = $_GET['name'];
  $file_delete = '../u/' . $file_name;
  unlink($file_delete);
  //header("location: $file_delete");
?>
```

`unlink` returns the error: `No such file or directory`, but if I try `header("location: $file_delete");` it opens the file (picture in this case).

Where may I be wrong?

Comment: Maybe `unlink()` doesn't accept relative paths, with "../" things.

Comment: try to `var_dump($file_delete)` to see if the path is correct.

Comment: @AmrAly it is correct as I mentioned if I use header("location: $file_delete"); it opens the file..

Comment: Bare in mind that your code would allow anyone to delete any file on your system that your Web server has permission to delete.

Comment: Improvements to grammar and formatting.

Comment: Are you aware that this code represents a huge security hole?

Comment: @Jack what should I do to make it more secure?

Comment: Avoid direct mapping from input parameter to filesystem. What if I point my browser to something like http://yoursite/page?name=../../../some/very/important/file? Just be aware of the security problem, and think if implement a more robust method worths it

Answer (score 5):

Get Absolute path first for the file to be deleted and check file exist before delete:

```
 $file_name = $_GET['name'];
 $base_dir = realpath($_SERVER["DOCUMENT_ROOT"]);
 $file_delete =  "$base_dir/your_inner_directories_path/$file_name";
 if (file_exists($file_delete)) {unlink($file_delete);}
```

Answer (score 0):

After some research, `unlink()` doesn't seem to allow you to use relative paths (with "../").

Here's an alternative:

```
<?php
  $file_name = $_GET['name'];
  $file_delete = dirname(__FILE__, 2) . '\\u\\' . $file_name;
  unlink($file_delete);
?>
```

`$file_delete` here is the **absolute** path to the file you want to delete.

Reminder: `/` is used for Unix systems, `\` for Windows.

PHP doc:
- http://php.net/manual/en/function.unlink.php
- http://php.net/manual/en/function.dirname.php

Comment: still the same problem.. unlink(C:\wamp64\www/u/test.jpg): No such file or directory in C:\wamp64\www\php\delete.php on line 7

Comment: Oh you use windows! You gotta use "\" slashes, and that should do it! I just edited my answer ahah x3

Comment: @Chunrand - (poke) Lemme know if that worked. If it did, feel free to tag my answer as accepted to close the topic!

Comment: Becouse the '\u\' is not supported I searched and I used "\\u\\" but again it gives me the same error... unlink(C:\wamp64\www\u\test.jpg): No such file or directory in C:\wamp64\www\php\delete.php

Comment: Is C:\wamp64\www\u\test.jpg the correct path to your file?

Comment: If you use [realpath()](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.realpath.php) to turn a relative path into an absolute path, you don't have to worry about different filesystems.

Answer (score 0):

I also had same issue with my code. What I did to solve the issue is:

First execute:

```
            var_dump($image_variable) // var_dump($file_delete) in your case.
```

It outputs: string(23)(my-image-path )

When I started counting string I just found 22 characters. I wondered where is the 23rd?
I checked and count carefully, at the end I found that there is space at the end of my image path. So I used php trim() function to remove white spaces. Like,

```
            $trimed_path = trim($image_variable)  // trim($file_delete) in your case.
```

Second: Now execute,

```
            unlink($trimed_path).
```

OR CHECK LIKE

```
            if(unlink($trimed_path))
            {
               echo "File Deleted";
            }
            else
            {
               echo "Error Deleting File";
            }
```

Answer (score 0):

Took me a couple of hours to figure out. As mentioned above unlink() is picky when it comes to paths.

Solution is:

1st) Define the path (this is how **Wordpress** does it btw):

```
define( 'ROOTPATH', dirname(dirname(__FILE__)) . '/' );
```

2) Do:

```
unlink(ROOTPATH.'public_html/file.jpg');
```